# Can I redistribute the result of Google Text-To-Speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

My question concerns the Google Text-to-Speech engine and in particular the following scenario.

1. The user writes a text in an Android application
2. The Text-to-Speech saves it as a .wav file

Am I allowed to upload this file to a web server and use it as part of a web application or are there licensing issues?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Per the Google Text to Speech API [Quotas and Limits page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/quotas):

> You can use the audio data files you create using Text-to-Speech in your applications or media in compliance with the [Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms) including compliance with all applicable law.

As far as I could interpret (I am not an attorney) from the aforementioned [Google Cloud Platform Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/terms) page there are no limits on audio file usage or distribution. Note that this is not explicitly stated; it is just not stated at all.